# Can anyone see why any input is not being saved within my Spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-preferences

I have created a spinner to display categories that the user can choose from and when it's selected I want the option to be saved somewhere.

I am using SharedPreference to store the value from the Spinner but for some reason it doesn't save the selected option, I was wondering why it's not saving?

activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="75dp"
                 android:id="@+id/statusFilter"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" />

  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:onClick="btnAdd"
                    android:text="@string/button_addLetter"
                    android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
                    android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Main Activity

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AnkoLogger, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    var letter = NewsItemModel()
    lateinit var app : MainApp
    var edit = false
    val IMAGE_REQUEST = 1

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_letter)
        app = application as MainApp
   


 val dropDownList = arrayOf("Latest", "Coronavirus Updates", "Crime", "Traffic and Travel", "Business", "Politics", "Weather", "Education", "Health")

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dropDownList)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
        statusFilter.adapter = adapter
        statusFilter.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
   val preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }

 override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 1){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",1).apply() //Puts 0, 1,2,3 with key "POSITION_KEY"
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 2){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",2).apply() //Puts 0, 1,2,3 with key "POSITION_KEY"
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 3){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",3).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 4){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",4).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 5){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",5).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 6){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",6).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 7){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",7).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 8){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",8).apply()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 9){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",9).apply()
                }
            }

            private fun condition1(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",1)
            }
            private fun condition2(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",2)
            }
            private fun condition3(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",3)
            }
            private fun condition4(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",4)
            }
            private fun condition5(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",5)
            }
            private fun condition6(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",6)
            }
            private fun condition7(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",7)
            }
            private fun condition8(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",8)
            }
            private fun condition9(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",9)
            }
        }


fun btnAdd(view: View) {
        val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = pref.edit()

        editor.putString("SELECTION", statusFilter.toString())

        editor.commit()

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

 val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val SELECTION = pref.getString("SELECTION", "")
        statusFilter(SELECTION)
        }
```

Comment: can't you just do `preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",position).apply()` instead of all your if statements

Comment: I guess, I didn't really mind too much about the redundant lines of code at the moment, just wanting to get my app working first, I was speaking to you yesterday i'm pretty sure right, you recommended some ways I could go abouts saving the input? Do you know where i've went wrong in my code to where it's not saving the input because no one is replying and I really don't know who else to turn to for a bit of help.

Comment: i'm saying maybe you should drop your if statement because i don't _think_ anything is selected yet, just try using `preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",position).apply()`

Comment: This is the 3th time you post the same question with different titles. Read the guidelines.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Still nothing, I put a log message underneath to see if it was even being called, it gets called when I open a Letter and when I choose any of the options underneath the Spinner so I don't see what is wrong

Comment: how do you know it isn't saving to shared prefs ? i can't really see where you're using the value you save ? i don't know why you're creating so many instances of shared prefs either, just create _one_ reference somewhere

Comment: I checked the Device Explorer and it does save the data but it doesn't display it within the app for some reason...

Comment: @a_local_nobody do you know why it mightn't display, ive done some more observing of other people trying sharedPreferences and it also saves for them but I still don't see why it's not displaying